# Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/played

Tags: android, api, mobile

i tried to implement google play games in the specific Login/savegame/leaderboard, into an android app.

i created the 2 oauth key (release and debug) and everything seems all right, because i can clearly login, make save game (that i see on my drive) and show the empty leaderboard. nice.

a day, i decided to check the api usage on the google api console, and i got this situation:

i have 100% errors on the call "games.applications.played", infact checking on the log i found the title of this post.
Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/played  ( i do not this call explicitly, i guess is during the login process)

but all the other call seems work right, and if i wouldn't look at the api usage probably i wouldn't notice.

do you have any idea?

Comment: if anyone have this problem, i have resolved removing the app from google play games on the games console and re-add it.

Answer (score 0):

Use google_leaderboard_app_id instead of google_leaderboard_id...
Your app id is 12 digit number and id is unique character,String and numbers..